# Does Microsoft's MS-SQL Server JDBC 3.0 driver include support for JTA?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jta

I read somewhere that in order to use JTA and Tomcat (I'm also using Hibernate) you need to use a JTA version of the JDBC driver. Is this true?
If so, does [this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=a737000d-68d0-4531-b65d-da0f2a735707#Overview) driver include JTA support?

Thanks,
Ittai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. See com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource.
You can also read more on XA transactions with MS SQL [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342335.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

But having the XA driver is necessary but not sufficient.  You have to have a JTA transaction manager as well, and that's not part of JDBC.

Comment: Yes thanks. I of course know that, The JTA Specific JDBC driver was the missing element

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) driver for MS SQL Server.
MS SQL Server, was built from a base acquired from Sybase, therefore they both use Tabular Data Stream as a protocol.

And as duffymo has said you'll need a JTA transaction manager such as :

- [JBossTS](http://www.jboss.org/jbosstm)
- or [Atomikos](http://www.atomikos.com/)

Comment: Worth noting that jTDS only seems to support emulating XA?

Comment: There is _"experimental true distributed transaction support"_, evidently: Set parameter `xaEmulation=false` in the connection string: http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html. Also, read the "README.XA" file from the repo: https://github.com/milesibastos/jTDS/blob/master/README.XA - _"This implementation is very
immature and cannot be recommended for production use at this stage. It may however be useful for development when true two phase commit support is required."_